# Printing, in a later function, the value returned in an earlier function

Tags: python

I've defined a function. I want that function to return a value. Then, later on in the script, I want to print that returned value *inside* of another defined function.

When I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'variable_name' is not defined.
```

Here's the defined function:

```
def get_number_of_purchased_items():
    item_quantity = input("Enter quantity purchased: ")
    item_quantity = int(item_quantity)
    return item_quantity
```

And here, later on in the script, is where I want to print "item_quantity":

```
def main():
    print("Number of purchased items: ", item_quantity).
```

A little more information, in case it helps:

The above is one part of my overall script. I'm defining several functions -- to get input from the user on (a) the type of item they want to purchase, (b) the number of items they purchase, (c) the price per unit, and (d) the tax rate.

Then I've created three functions that take arguments, based on the returned values of the four above functions, to calculate (a) the subtotal, (b) the tax, and (c) the total cost.

Then I'm sticking all of these functions inside another function, main(), which, when printed, acts as a sales receipt -- see below. (I've included the "item_quantity" value I want returned, the one which results in a NameError.)

```
def main():
    get_retail_item_description()
    get_number_of_purchased_items()
    get_price_per_unit()
    get_tax_rate()
    print("Sales receipt: ")
    print("Number of purchased items: ", item_quantity)
    print("Unit price: ", )
    print("Tax Rate: ", )
    print("Subtotal: ", )
    print("Tax: ", )
   print("Total: ", )
```

Thanks for your patience and support on this.

Comment: You have a good start. Look up "variables"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you use `return`, but do not declare a variable to hold it.
`item_quantity` is a variable in the function, therefore `main` do not know what it is. You have two ways:

```py
item_quantity = get_number_of_purchased_items()
```

or:

```py
print("Number of purchased items: ", get_number_of_purchased_items())
```

But #2 will be awkward, so I suggest to go with #1.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Let me see if I have this right:

I've defined the function get_number_of_items_purchased(), which returns a value. But that returned value isn't assigned a variable, so once the function's done, the value disappears. (Is this because the item_quantity is a local variable, which is "refreshed" each time the function is called?)

When I call the get_number_of_items_purchased() within the main() function, I need to assign the returned value to a variable. Then I can use that variable later on in my print() statement.

Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it!

Comment: You are right. Variables inside functions stay inside the function, so when you return you have to assign a variable to hold the value.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `item_quantity` with `get_number_of_purchased_items()`.